# Post request from external website to Rails App is not routed through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, heroku, routes

I am trying to send data from an external website to a Rails app but the post request is not routed through correctly.

The Rails app has the route

```html
  post '/submit_text/' => 'activities#submitText', as: :submitText
```

The code of the corresponding controller action is

```html
    before_filter :submitText
    protect_from_forgery :except => :submitText
    def submitText    
      puts "in submitText"
      puts params[:text]
      puts "end of submitText "
    end
```

I am trying to send data from an external website to the Rails app like this

```html
<form action="https://todo-list-study.herokuapp.com/submit_text/" method= "post">

    
        <textarea name="response[text]" rows="25" cols="75" id="answer_text">
    
        </textarea>
    
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="test" onclick="recordAnswer()">    
    
</form>
```

When I submit data from the external website, the Rails app receives it but it does not pass it on to the specified controller action. Here is what happens according to the Heroku log file:

```html
heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/submit_text/" host=todo-list-study.herokuapp.com request_id=fee72511-ad1e-41c3-ae4c-d4b3395e6afd fwd="24.7.71.184" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=19ms status=500 bytes=1754 protocol=https
```

Unfortunately, that is all that happens. Given that the put statement at the beginning of the method is not executed I conclude that it is not being called. This happens even though both the Rails app and the external website run on the HTTPS protocol.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: look into the configs in config/environments/development.rb

Comment: What should I be looking for there?

Answer (score 0):

The router is finding an action for that call, otherwise it would have responded with a `404` instead of a `500`, which indicates that there's an internal error.

Assuming that you're not trying to send back a response with content back to the client, try adding a call to render so that your controller sends back a response instead of trying to find a view template to render, which is where I'm guessing the issue is.

For example, try updating your code to:

```
def submitText    
  puts "in submitText"
  puts params[:text]
  puts "end of submitText "

  render nothing: true
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I have adopted your suggestion and tried submitting the form again, but unfortunately, the log still ends at "heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/submit_text/" host=todo-list-study.herokuapp.com request_id=88c59a3a-e119-422f-b946-54c4499389a6 fwd="24.7.71.184" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=19ms status=200 bytes=873 protocol=https".

Comment: This time you're getting a status 200 back though, so at least it was successfully submitted. Are you not seeing the "in submitText" before that line in the logs?

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that. I guess that means progress. But no, for some reason I am not seeing "in submitText" in the log file. Where might the internal error come from?

Comment: The internal error would have been because you were missing the render clause, in which it would have tried to render the submitText template which I'm guessing does not exist. Are you seeing any app level logs through Heroku at all?

Comment: That's possible, but why could it be that "in submitText" is still not appearing in the log? The most recent app-level log was "INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4 port=11002" which appeared before "heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up". Could it be that there was an error since then and that's why the app is not working anymore at this point?

Comment: Ah! This is my bad. Try using `puts` instead of `Rails.logger.info` as I initially suggested. I'm going to guess that you aren't redirecting rails logs to STDOUT, and instead its still logging to `production.log`, in which case it won't appear in heroku logs. Checkout https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#writing-to-your-log and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4 to see how to get rails logs to appear in the heroku logs

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, nothing appears in the log even when I use puts. This is very strange.